# Python- For Loop - Increment each index position for each tuple in list

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I've searched around for a possible way to do this. I'm trying to make a loop that will go through my list of tuple pairs. Each index contains data that I will calculate and append to a list through each loop run until the end of the list of tuples is reached. Currently using a for loop, but I might use while loop.

```
index_tuple = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
total_list = []

for index_pairs in index_tuple:
    total_list.append(index_tuple[0][1] - index_tuple[0][0])
```

What I'm trying to get the loop to do:

```
(index_tuple[0][1] - index_tuple[0][0])#increment
(index_tuple[1][1] - index_tuple[1][0])#increment
(index_tuple[2][1] - index_tuple[2][0])#increment
```

Then I guess my final question is it possible to increment index position with a while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension is the best solution for this problem, and  [Malik Brahimi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577776/21945) is the way to go.

Nevertheless, sticking with your for loop, you need to reference `index_pairs` in the body of the loop because this variable is assigned each tuple from `index_tuple` as the loop iterates. You do not need to maintain an index variable. A corrected version would be this:

```
index_tuple = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
total_list = []

for index_pairs in index_tuple:
    total_list.append(index_pairs[1] - index_pairs[0])

>>> print total_list
[1, 1, 1]
```

A cleaner version which unpacks the tuples from the list directly into 2 variables would be:

```
index_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
total_list = []

for a, b in index_tuples:
    total_list.append(b - a)

>>> print total_list
[1, 1, 1]
```

You also asked about using a while loop to achieve the same. Use an integer to keep track of the current index and increment it by one on each iteration of the loop:

```
index_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
total_list = []

index = 0
while index < len(index_tuples):
    total_list.append(index_tuples[index][1] - index_tuples[index][0])
    index += 1

>>> print total_list
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a list comprehension. This iterates the list, unpacks each tuple to two values `a` and `b`, then it subtracts the first item from the second and inserts this new subtracted value into the new list.

```
totals = [b - a for a, b in index_tuple]
```